Tell sheet to be ignored at printing/pdf export
In my OpenOffice-Calc document (*.ods-file) I have several sheets, where I would like to export just a specific amount of them as a pdf file (or even print these specific ones).
I know, there is e.g. in the printing dialogue a edit field for enumerate the pages, which should be exported.
But is there a way to tell a specific sheet, that this sheet should NOT be printed or exported as pdf (so exclude it completely) ?

Do you want this to be remember across different clients/computers, or does it only have to be configured for a single computer?

it should be included in the document. So I can exchange this doc with different computers/clients

Which format are you using to save these sheets, or does that matter?

I am using *.ods files
